# infinite sum and equivalence

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

I'm studying generating functions and I came across the Fibonacci number generating function. Given the Fibonacci succession:
$$f_n= \begin{cases} 
      0 & n=0 \\
      1 &n= 1 \\
      f_{n-1}+ f_{n-2}  & n>1 
   \end{cases}$$
text says that we could follow the following procedure in order to find the generating function ("$F(z)$"). For every $n > 1$ we have that
$$ f_n = f_{n-1}+ f_{n-2}$$
and multiplying each side for $z^n$ ($z$ is a real variable) results in
$$ f_nz^n = f_{n-1}z^n+ f_{n-2}z^n$$
Here it comes the passage that I don't understand: "now we sum for every $n >1$ " and the results is
$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty f_nz^n = \sum_{n=2}^\infty f_{n-1}z^n+ \sum_{n=2}^\infty f_{n-2}z^n$$
why this equivalence holds? it's because we know that the power series converges to a function? Thinking about this problem, I got confused more and more because for example
$${1\over{n(n+1)} }= {1\over{n} } - {1\over{n+1} } $$
and reiterating the same reasoning for every $n > 0$ we can't say that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over{n(n+1)} }= \sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over{n} } - \sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over{n+1} } $$
because RHS is convergent and LHS is divergent. Basically the question is why for Fibonacci the equation holds and for the second example not? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I remember my teacher telling me that generating functions aren't meant to converge or play nice, they're just convenient ways of formally manipulating coefficients in series. Although it's possible he was just hand-waving things for us, so not sure...

Comment: @RaadShaikh yeah in fact at the end of the example you reach a nice formula for every Fibonacci number, without solving the recursion. What I don't understand is why I can say that the equation still holds, because that is the central point for going forward with the examples and I guess I am too poor in analysis to appreciate what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Fix a z, $\sum_{n=2}^\infty f_{n-1}z^n+\sum_{n=2}^\infty f_{n-2}z^n$ is finite iff
$z\sum_{n=2}^\infty f_{n-1}z^{n-1}$ and $z^2\sum_{n=2}^\infty f_{n-2}z^{n-2}$ are finite, which is the case iff $\sum_n f_n z^n$ is finite.
This reasonment is not feasible for your second example.

Comment: The abbreviation of "if and only if" is "iff", not "iif"

Comment: indeed i don't know why i wrote iif ^^

Comment: Why is convergent? because we know a priori that is the Fibonacci sequence? So is the central focus when the series converges or not?